# Como incluir minimum_should_match na query do elasticsearch dsl?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Estou tentado usar o `minimum_should_match` como está na [documentação](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html)

```
q = Q('bool',
    must=[Q('match', title='python')],
    should=[Q(...), Q(...)],
    minimum_should_match=1
)
s = Search().query(q)
```

Mas quando incluo na minha query ela não retorna nada.

```
termo = 'Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN'

q = Q('bool', must=[Q('match', TermoBusca=termo)],minimum_should_match=1)
s = Search(using=es, index='produtos').query(q)
print(s.to_dict())

produtosEncontrados: list = s.execute()
for produto in produtosEncontrados:
    print(produto.Descricao)
```

Se eu removo o parâmetro (`minimum_should_match=1`) a consulta retorna resultados normalmente.

```
    termo = 'Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN'

    q = Q('bool', must=[Q('match', TermoBusca=termo)])
    s = Search(using=es, index='produtos').query(q)
    print(s.to_dict())

    produtosEncontrados: list = s.execute()
    for produto in produtosEncontrados:
        print(produto.Descricao)
```

Saida:

Query gerada:

```
{'query': {'match': {'TermoBusca': 'Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN'}}}
```

Saida:

- Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN
- Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro azul royal 301176 Pelikan CX 6 UN
- Tinta p/caneta tinteiro 30ml preto 301051 Pelikan PT 1 UN
- Tinta p/caneta tinteiro 30ml azul escuro 301028 Pelikan PT 1 UN
- Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro azul CA32005A Crown BT 3 UN
- Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preta CA32005P Crown BT 3 UN
- Caneta tinteiro Capricci prata YW32616S Crown CX 1 UN
- Caneta tinteiro Capricci preta YW32616P Crown CX 1 UN
- Caneta tinteiro Regent neutra YW39422N Crown CX 1 UN
- Cartucho p/Brother preto LC3039BK Brother CX 1 UN

Já procurei em todo lugar e não entendi o que estou fazendo de errado.
Minha intenção é filtrar pelo campo `TermoBusca` 100% do termo informado. Como na consulta abaixo, só que usando a [DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
    termo = 'Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN'
    query_body = {
            "sort" : [
                { "Prioridade" : {"order" : "desc"}},
                { "CurvaABC" : {"order" : "desc"}},
                "_score"
            ],
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "TermoBusca": {
                        "query": termo,
                        "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                    }
                }
            },
        "size": 60
    }

    result = es.search(index="produtos", body=query_body)
    print()

    for hit in result['hits']['hits']:
        print(hit['_source']['TermoBusca'])
    self.assertEqual(56, len(result['hits']['hits']))
```

Saida:

- Cartucho p/caneta tinteiro preto 301218 Pelikan CX 6 UN

Comment: Já viu este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984706/default-value-of-minimum-should-match) ?

Comment: @PauloMarques, não tinha visto, mas ele também está usando as querys do elasticsearch e não do elasticsearch DSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parâmetro `minimum_should_match` deve ser usado em conjunto com cláusulas opcionais do tipo `should`. Quando `minimum_should_match=1` um item só será retornado pela consulta se ao menos uma das cláusulas `should` for verdadeira.
A sua consulta não possui cláusulas `should`. Ela possui apenas uma cláusula `must`. Por definição, quando você usa `must`, todos os itens retornados devem satisfazer a condição da cláusula. Logo, a sua *query* com `must` já filtra pelo campo `TermoBusca` em 100% dos casos (o uso de `minimum_should_match` não é necessário).

Em versões antigas do Elasticsearch (antes da versão 5), na ausência de cláusulas `should` o parâmetro `minimum_should_match` era ignorado. Esse comportamento mudou e em versões modernas do Elasticsearch. Hoje em dia uma *query* com `minimum_should_match` maior que o número de cláusulas `should` não retorna nenhum item.

Essa mudança impactou alguns sistemas que construíam cláusulas `should` dinamicamente.

Eu tive que lidar com esse problema no passado após uma atualização do Elasticsearch ter quebrado a funcionalidade de busca de um sistema. No caso, quando nenhum filtro opcional era especificado as buscas pararam de retornar resultados. A solução foi modificar a lógica que construía a busca para apenas incluir o parâmetro `minimum_should_match` quando a quantidade de cláusulas `should` for maior do que 1.
Mais detalhes sobre esse problema podem ser encontradas no seguinte *issue* do GitHub (em inglês):

- [*Issue #21844: Bool 'must' query with "minimum_should_match": "1", then result is empty*](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21844)

---

### Update:

A massa de dados postada pelo Marconcilio me chamou a atenção para o fato de que o parâmetro `minimum_should_match` está na *query* interna. O comportamento desejado pelo OP, no caso, é que a consulta apenas retorne items onde `TermoBusca` contenha 100% dos termos na string `termo`. Na DSL do *Python* podemos reconstruir a query interna com um `dict`:

```
 q = Q('match', TermoBusca={'query': termo, 'minimum_should_match': '100%'})
```

Comment: tem um exemplo de como monta a query com o elasticsearch dsl? usando o "minimum_should_match": "100%" como na query que eu montei e feito a busca por   **papel sulfite chamex a4 75g** apenas os produtos que tem todas essas palavras são retornados.

Comment: o minimum_should_match=1 foi apenas um exemplo de como está na documentação, mas na query quero que sejá 100%

Comment: O seu terceiro exemplo (com `must` e sem `minimum_should_match`) não faz exatamente o que você precisa? `minimum_should_match='100%'` funciona se sua query possuir uma ou mais cláusulas `should` (conforme o seu primeiro exemplo retirado da documentação). Para fazer o segundo exemplo funcionar basta trocar `must` por `should`, porém isso não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Tentei de de várias formas mais não consegui.

Comment: Oi Marconcilio, para mim não está claro qual o problema. Na sua questão você diz que seu terceiro exemplo (DSL, sem `minimum_should_match`) retorna os dados certo? O que estou dizendo é que o seu exemplo está correto e que o `minimum_should_match` é desnecessário. Se os dados não estão batendo com o quarto exemplo (da consulta), valeria a pena atualizar a questão com um MVCE + massa de dados, demonstrando quais dados estão sendo retornados a mais ou a menos usando a DSL do que na consulta.

Comment: Acho que a issue citada no post foi resolvida no 7.5.2

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, atualizei com minha saida de dados e com a query gerada no 3º exemplo.  no 3º exemplo ele traz 10 item e no 4º ele traz apenas o item que corresponde 100% do termo informado. no caso no ele só tem esse item no meu index produtos

Comment: Ah, que interessante. Não tinha percebido que o `minimum_should_match` está no mesmo nível do que o termo. Eu não tenho um ambiente para testar agora, mas você já tentou fazer isso usando um dicionário? E.g., `q = Q('match', TermoBusca={'query': termo, 'minimum_should_match': '100%'})`

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, não tinha testado assim, funcionou certinho aqui vlw